# Revert old wordpress site redirecting to new domain after cloning

Tags: wordpress

After cloning my wordpress website, when entering the old url I am redirected to the new one (also when trying to access the wp-login.php page). How can I remove this redirect and access the old website? I may have used either Duplicator or wp-clone plugins (was a while ago so don't quite remember).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your wp-config.php file, which is located in the root directory of your WordPress installation, for lines that define WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL. If they're present, change them to the correct URL for the old website.

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://your-old-domain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://your-old-domain.com');
```

Also update the URLs in the database.

Comment: Thanks. "Also update the URLs in the database." - could you please give more details on this, i.e. which tables/fields need to be updated?

Comment: https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-change-wordpress-urls-in-mysql-database-using-phpmyadmin

please refer below tutorial for more details